# How to submit an ajax form post that has loaded dynamically in a bootstrap modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm going to make this as concise as possible. I'm loading this form dynamically in a modal window in Bootstrap. But when I submit it...instead of posting via ajax, the whole page is submitted. What can I do to submit via AJAX (in the background) while saving the state of the page? Here is the code that loads into the modal div element:

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
       $('.modal form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "index2.html",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("multiform").serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Successfully submitted.")
                }
            });
       }); 
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form name="multiform" id="multiform" action="index2.html" method="POST" >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"  value="Ravi"/> <br/>
    Age :<input type="text" name="age"  value="1" /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 2px;  height: 27px; width: 89px;" ></input>
</form>
```

Comment: BTW, if I hard code the form in the modal window and submit via ajax, things work as expected. It just happens when the form is loaded dynamically.

Comment: Try with `<input type="button"> or <button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to surround the code with $(document).ready() and I needed to reference the data to serialize via '.modal form'. Once I did that, everything worked well.

```js
 $(document).ready( function() {
       $('.modal form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "index2.html",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('.modal form').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
       }); 
    });
```